# Cannot indent a python-sphinx .rst file in relation to another

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to indent a .rst file indexed in the document, without success.

[sidebar menu with items not indented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGzQ6.png)

I would love to have samples, contrasts and counts indented after introduction, without having to merge samples, contrasts and counts to the introduction.

This is the github branch:

https://github.com/bigomics/omicsplayground-doc/tree/upload-pgx-gmt-doc, and I want to indent the

I tried several tutorials online and chatgpt, nothing worked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you define the `.rst` file that has the toctree with those links you have to [nest the toctrees correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934884) (I'm assuming list levels in the side bar is what you mean by "allign"), it seems you are using [RTD theme see the customizing options](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html). If on the other hand by "allign" you mean custom CSS see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32079202).